# Pausing ffmpeg: "slow motion" after resume

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to pause/resume ffmpeg process during encoding. The OS is Windows.

I pause ffmpeg.exe and resume it after a while. The problem is, that during replaying of created movie, it looks like played in "slow-motion" for some time since the moment of pausing. After a while replay speed catches up with actual frame rate.

The "slow-motion time" seems similar to pause-time, but it is rather not 1:1 relation.

I use Win32 process/thead API to pause and resume ffmpeg process. But it behaves exactly same when paused/resumed using Windows resource monitor, or using keyboard Pause key.

Interestingly, same problem occurs when you enter 'c' key at ffmpeg input and wait a while instead of entering command. Looks like the process blocks at I/O function and then has a problem with frame timestamps.

I'm neither ffmpeg nor multimedia expert, but it looks to me like problem with some kind of time-stamps and the gap between the moment ffmpeg is paused and resumed.

Is there maybe some ffmpeg commands or filters that could fix it? Or a better way to pause/resume it during recording?

Comment: What's your ffmpeg command?

Answer (score 0):

@Gyan: preparing sample command line in response to your comment, and reducing it to simplest possible options set, I found a problem:

I'm using DirectShow device as input and specified "-r" for input frame rate. This is incorrect, as can be found e.g. here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow#Specifyinginputframerate. So, I replaced -r with -framerate and it is OK now. Suspend/resume works as expected.

Thanks for hint and sorry for bothering people before RTFM